# How do you setup developing your own pallet in substrate

Tags: substrate

There is a tutorial for substrate that shows how to add a pre-existing pallet to a substrate node. However, it doesn't show how to create your own pallet.

What changes would be required in Cargo.toml and where in the directory structure should the pallet src file be located?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of links out there, I think they should be enough to answer your question:

- More or less exactly what you asked for: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-a-pallet/
- Template for pallet: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-pallet-template
- A more conceptual description: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/pallets

---

Answering the exact questions from the comment:

> (1) where in the directory structure the pallet should be located and

Anywhere is possible. As long as you import it into the Cargo.toml of the top level runtime (which can live in any path) it is fine. Usually, similar [to how `node-template` is structures, they are placed in one folder](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/master/pallets).

> (2) what changes are required in the Cargo.toml file so that substrate will know where to look for the pallet since its not coming from a preexisting pallet.

This sounds more like a Rust question of "how do I import another crate", but I think again the node-template example can be useful: See how the top level runtime's Cargo file (placed in `/runtime`) is importing a pallet (placed in `/pallets/template`): https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/runtime/Cargo.toml#L28

Comment: Thanks for your response :) Those links refer to adding a pre-existing pallet from a crate repository. I need to know instead, how to go about creating your own pallet from scratch. I'm looking for specific direction on (1) where in the directory structure the pallet should be located and (2) what changes are required in the Cargo.toml file so that substrate will know where to look for the pallet since its not coming from a preexisting pallet.